# Floating point rounding in shell

Tags: linux, bash, floating-point

```
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.495
41.49
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.485
41.49
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.475
41.47
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.465
41.47
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.455
41.46
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.445
41.44
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.435
41.44
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.425
41.42
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.415
41.42
$ printf "%0.2f\n" 41.405
41.40
```

Why are the numbers with an uneven number as the second decimal not correctly rounded and even ones are? Additionally what is wrong with .445 that it never gets rounded?

Comment: They all look correctly rounded to me.

Comment: What shell are you using, say, `bash`, `tcsh`, or something else? This looks like `printf` in shell instead of C or C++.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @JamesKanze According to which rounding scheme? I know of none where .495 becomes .49 but .485 becomes .48 -- no, floating point arithmetic is not a rounding scheme. It's an accident.

Comment: @delnan: floating point arithmetic is not an accident.

Comment: I am using bash. Thanks for mention it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - John that link. That link John. That link is goood!

Comment: The basic issue is there are two roundings: One when the text, such as “41.495” is converted to an internal floating-point representation, and a second when the internal value is formatted for printing. With numbers close to rounding points issues like these happen, because a number that is exactly on the border for one rounding (the decimal rounding for output) is not exactly representable in the destination of the other rounding (internal binary).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with floating-point, but not with double-precision.

When you write

```
printf "%0.2f\n" 41.495
```

on your system, `printf` first rounds `41.495` to the closest x87 80-bit floating-point number[1].  How does that work?  First write 41.495 in binary:

```
b101001.0111 11101011100001010001 11101011100001010001 11101011100001010001 ...
```

(the separated groups repeat ad infinitum).  Now we round this number to have 64 binary digits:

```
b101001.0111111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001
```

This is the number that is actually formatted by printf.  Written in decimal, it is exactly:

```
41.4949999999999999990285548534529880271293222904205322265625
```

as you can see, it is just a little bit less than 41.495, so when printf rounds it to two fractional digits, it rounds *down*, and `41.49` is printed.

Now look at 41.485; after rounding to 64 binary digits, we get the value:

```
41.48500000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

which is just a little bit *bigger* than 41.485, so printf rounds it *up*.

On my system, there is a warning about this in the printf manage:

> Since the floating point numbers are translated from ASCII to floating-point and then back again, floating-point precision may be lost.

---

1. bash doesn't use the x87 format on all operating systems (indeed, it isn't even available on all architectures); on some other systems these values will be interpreted as doubles (and therefore rounded to 53 bits instead of 64), and the results will differ.

Answer (score 2):

I'd lay big odds on it has to do with the [IEEE Double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) type.  The long-and-short of that is that any decimal number is internally represented with exponent and fraction components, but not in decimals, but in binary.  That's not a 100% explanation, and the article explains it much better, but basically floating-point numbers are represented "close" to how they are, not necessarily exactly what you typed in.  Thus the rounding can get a bit odd as well.

Read the wiki article.  That should help.  And if you need exactness, look in to other number representations that don't use this standard.

Comment: `printf` is only converting the string to a float when it needs to--when reducing the number of decimal points. In Python, you can see that `41495/1000` is `41.494999999999997`, which would be rounded down to `41.49`.

Comment: If it is, I am a bit curious into why this type of error is not mentioned in the wiki and no easily read information and examples are mentioned there. The common mathematics teaches us that this is they way it should work, so common sens dictates that by logic it should work. So information relating to this should have been mentioned there. +1 for pointing it out Kevin.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: Wikipedia is not a tutorial.

Comment: This is not the result of double-precision rounding. (This is easily testable, and I did so, and double-precision rounding does not reproduce the stated results.) It may be the result of rounding in a different precision. Single-precision rounding gives the stated results, and rounding in another precisions might as well.

Comment: Fair enough on it's single instead of double.  It was mainly a "decimals not working as expected, and double is usually default, and a fair number of people don't understand how floats/doubles are stored, so..." hence the link.  You're right that it may not be the exact cause, but I was trying to give clues as to on the surface why floating-point numbers don't work as always expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell or printf command may be using an extended-precision floating point, such as Intel’s 80-bit floating point. `printf` is implemented directly in some shells and is available as a separate executable, such as in `/usr/bin/printf`.

The closest single-precision value (in IEEE 754) to 41.495 is 41.494998931884765625. Thus, when the text “41.495” is interpreted as a single-precision value, it stands for exactly 41.494998931884765625. When this value is rounded to two decimal digits after the decimal point, it is 41.49, because the “499…” rounds down.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.495 is 41.4949999999999999990285548534529880271293222904205322265625. Thus, when the text “41.495” is interpreted, it stands for exactly 41.4949999999999999990285548534529880271293222904205322265625. When this is rounded to two decimal digits after the decimal point, it is 41.49.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.485 is 41.48500000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. When rounded, this is 41.49.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.475 is 41.474999999999999998612221219218554324470460414886474609375. When rounded, this is 41.47.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.465 is 41.4650000000000000001387778780781445675529539585113525390625. When rounded, this is 41.47.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.455 is 41.45500000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875. When rounded, this is 41.46.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.445 is 41.444999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875. When rounded, this is 41.44.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.435 is 41.4350000000000000012490009027033011079765856266021728515625. When rounded, this is 41.44.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.425 is 41.4249999999999999993061106096092771622352302074432373046875. When rounded, this is 41.42.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.415 is 41.415000000000000000832667268468867405317723751068115234375. When rounded, this is 41.42.

The closest extended-precision value to 41.405 is 41.4049999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. When rounded, this is 41.40.

Answer (score 0):

You can have bash show you exactly what it's doing internally: `printf "%0.20f\n" 41.495` By trial and error, the next smallest number that registers a different representation is: `printf "%0.20f\n" 41.495000000000000001`, which is actually MORE precise than double precision.  Actually, this all the printf command.  bash does not actually understand floating point numbers.

Comment: printf is a built-in in GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12). The printf executable in /usr/bin/printf shows different results from the bash printf.