# Why do I get different output on linux and OS/X

Tags: c, linux, macos, printf, sh

I was trying a very simple `printf` test:

```
printf "%.16f\n" 5.10
```

On linux I got this output: `5.100000000000000000` which is expected.

But the very same test on OS/X produces this: `5.0999999999999996`

Why does `printf` produce different output?

**EDIT**: This is not C code, `printf` is also a command-line utility, handy for scripts and tests.

The equivalent C program below produces `5.100000000000000000`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%.16f\n", 5.10);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: The plot thickens... to make this more interesting for linux users, if I run this command as `nobody`, I get the same behavior as on OS/X:

```
chqrlie$ printf "%.18f\n" 5.10
5.100000000000000000
chqrlie$ su nobody -c 'printf "%.18f\n" 5.10'
5.099999999999999645
```

Comment: Does the C program you show produce the same result on both Linux and macOS? If it does then the problem is either in the implementation of the `printf` commands, or in the shells. Which shells are you using on each system?

Comment: Yes, I get different output on different OS, but the C program produces the same output on both OSes :)

Comment: the simple answer would be that the macos chain of shell utilities is from the 80s (before GPL) and broken. Use GNU/Linux. Would you accept that?

Comment: @hek2mgl: the utility chain does behave differently, but is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @chqrlie this is not a bug nor a feature, it is inherent to floats! 5.1 can't be stored exactly, then any printing not so far from 5.1 is acceptable. Don't be fooled by the fact that some printing function gives you 5.1 in return...

Comment: @chqrlie It has everything to do with [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) You understand that there is no canonical 16-digit stringification of the floating point number produced by parsing the string "5.10", right? That the details of that are entirely implementation-dependent?

Comment: With `printf(1)`, I get 5.099999999999999645 on OS X and Linux, without having to do anything weird with sudo. EDIT: printf is a shell builtin (zsh on linux, bash on OS X). Using /usr/bin/printf gives 5.10... on linux, and the long number on OS X)

Comment: Looks like some implementations use `long double` instead of `double`.

Comment: When 5.10 is stored as a 64-bit IEEE-754, the exact value is 5.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375. If you print that with 16 digits after the decimal, the correctly rounded value is 5.0999999999999996. So the only question is why does the linux command print something other than that.

Comment: I reopened this question. The difference between printf  on different OS and between the host's C library itself(!) is indeed interesting and if I understood correctly the main point the OP is asking about

Comment: Are you using the same shells (and versions) on both systems?

Comment: `printf` is a built-in command in some shells (e.g. Bash). The users "chqrlie" and "nobody" may be using different shells, one with a built-in `printf` command and one without.

Comment: [Floating point rounding in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12113612/608639)

Comment: I'm on an iMac running High Sierra and when I run printf "%.16f\n" 5.10  I get 5.1000000000000000

Comment: I agree with above that you're running different versions. for each user try `type printf`. You may get `printf is a shell builtin` OR `printf is /usr/bin/printf`. Then you can research from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Both the GNU implementation and the MacOS (FreeBSD) implementation of `printf` are different programs. Both aim to be compatible with the POSIX standard.

POSIX leaves the representation of floating point numbers open to the implementation of printf. Their argumentation is that all calculation in shell is integer anyway.

> The floating-point formatting conversion specifications of printf() are not required because all arithmetic in the shell is integer arithmetic. The awk utility performs floating-point calculations and provides its own printf function. The bc utility can perform arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic, but does not provide extensive formatting capabilities. (This printf utility cannot really be used to format bc output; it does not support arbitrary precision.) Implementations are encouraged to support the floating-point conversions as an extension.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

---

PS:

```
5.1
```

is *not* a floating point number in bash. bash does not support floating numbers.

`5.1` is a string, interpreted by `printf` depending on the locale(!)

```
theymann@theymann-laptop:~/src/sre/inventory-schema$ LANG=en_US.UTF8 printf "%.16f\n" 5.10
5.1000000000000000
theymann@theymann-laptop:~/src/sre/inventory-schema$ LANG=de_DE.UTF8 printf "%.16f\n" 5.10
bash: printf: 5.10: Ungültige Zahl. # << German: Bad Number
0,0000000000000000
```

Note: In Germany we use , as the decimal separator.

---

The difference in the output between a normal user and nobody must the shell which is used. some shells, like busybox come with their own implementation of `printf`. Btw, I'm extremely surprised that nobody is allowed to execute commands on your system!

Comment: You seem to have a good track, but how do you explain the difference observed in my latest EDIT

Comment: @chqrlie may be one implementation is not calling C with the same format string...

Comment: Looks like your shell and the system shell are different.

Comment: @chqrlie is the same _printf_ command called or not when it is you / nobody ?  If yes what difference do you see when you execute _printf_ under _strace_ in the two cases (to explain a diff in the configurations)

Comment: @bruno: the difference is intriguing indeed... The reason is `nobody`'s default shell is `/bin/sh` and mine is `/bin/bash`. `/bin/sh` uses an internal implementation of the `printf` command which uses `float` arithmetic whereas `/usr/bin/printf` uses `double` arithmetics on GNU/linux and `float` arithmetics on BSD based OS/X

Answer (score 3):

This is because floating point types mostly can't represent exact values. For example using an online IEE754 tool you got:

[image]

So `5.1` is not exactly representable using this format.

Then `printf` (or whatever) is free to format/print any value that it thinks suitable for the user.

Comment: While your answer has valid points, it does not explain the observed behavior. I am requesting 16 decimals, is the `printf` utility bogus on OS/X?

Comment: That does not explain why the `printf` command gives 5.0999999999999996 while the printf/() C call gives 5.100000000000000000 on osx. Nor does it explain why the `printf` command gives different output on osx vs linux.

Comment: No, OS/X printf is just fair enough and gives you the representation of the stored value. I personally dislike very much this kind of printf cheating...

Comment: @nos every implementation is free to print the value as it wants, floatings are not exact... You may think "rounding" to 5.1 on print is a good thing but it is not at this cheats on you what is stored.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: come on, the behavior of floating point math is much more precisely defined than you infer.

Comment: @chqrlie What are you talking about? If the value stored is 5.0999999904... what was the initial value? You can't tell, so printing 5.1 is just cheating.

Comment: @chqrlie the printing of floats is not so well defined. Math is well defined but printing is not math.

Comment: @chqrlie That's incorrect. Proper conversion from a string to a floating-point number is well-defined. In the other direction, it is absolutely not. As an example, Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 differ in conversion behavior.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: “Printing” is conversion. It is a conversion from one representation to another, whether it is integer to hexadecimal or floating-point to decimal. As with all conversions, the result should be the representable value closest to the mathematical result (e.g., when 16 digits are request, the number with 16 digits closest to the source operand). Conversion operations are defined in IEEE 754, and good algorithms for implementing them are known, so programming languages and other software should bind to IEEE 754.

Comment: The operation of `printf` (C or shell) when formatting floating-point data as decimal is the operation contemplated by IEEE 754 5.12, “Details of conversion between floating-point data and external character sequences.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe you know that there is no canonical decimal writing of all real numbers... Even "simplest" ones like 1.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: That has no relevance. The question here is what the digits are, not whether scientific notation or fixed-point is used or whether an unnecessary “+”, leading “0”, or trailing “.” are used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, everybody knowns that (for example) 1 and 0.999999.... are different writings of the same number, so which one to write? You have the choice. In the case of "approximations" the problem is worst... How one can decide that 5.0999999906... is 5.1 ? May be it is not!

Comment: Between “1” and ”0.999…”, “1” is the canonical form. Furthermore, if one were considering producing the “0.999…” form, the rounding rules would result in “1”. The way one can decide that 5.0999999906... is not 5.1 is to observe there is a non-zero difference between them; they differ by more than .0000000002. Please stop this nonsense. Good behavior is well known to floating-point practitioners; it is documented, specified, presented in textbooks, and well established.